# Find all function such that $f(x)-f(y) = (x -y)g(\sqrt{xy})$

Tags: functional-equations

Find all functions $f, g$ that satisfy the functional equation
$$
f(x)-f(y)= (x -y)g(\sqrt{xy}) \quad \forall\ x,y>0.
$$

Comment: try it yourself

Comment: Try to obtain an equation that only involves $g$.

Comment: I do it and i have this equation: (x^2-1)g(x)-(y^2-1)g(y)=(x^2-y^2)g(xy).If  F(x)=(x^2-1)g(x) then we have the equation: ((X^2)*(y^2)-1)(F(x)-F(y))=(x^2-y^2)F(xy). I can't find any solution.Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** First fix $y=1$, this shows what $f$ *has to be*, in terms of $g$. Then fix another $y$ as well.

Comment: I do it and i have this equation: (x^2-1)g(x)-(y^2-1)g(y)=(x^2-y^2)g(xy).If F(x)=(x^2-1)g(x) then we have the equation: ((X^2)*(y^2)-1)(F(x)-F(y))=(x^2-y^2)F(xy). I can't find any solution.Can you help me

Answer (score 0):

Since the functional equation is
 $\;f(x)-f(y)= (x -y)g(\sqrt{xy})\;\;\forall x,y>0\;$ we can write it as
 $\;g(x) = (f(x t)-f(x/t))/(x t-x/t).\;$ Assuming that $f(x):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n\;$ then the equation is
$$g(x)=c_1+c_2x(1/t+t)+c_3x^2(1/t^2+1+t^2)+c_4x^3(1/t^3+1/t+t+t^3)+\cdots.$$
The coefficients of $g(x)$ must be constants, so $\;c_n=0\;$ for all $n>1.$ Now $f(x)=c_0+c_1x.$